# Busca de palavra em planilha do excel e retorno da linha inteira que contem essa palavra em PYTHON

Tags: microsoft-excel, python-3.x

Olá, tudo bom? Sou iniciante em Python e gostaria de rodar um script que dada uma planilha em excel, o usuário pudesse buscar uma palavra dentro dessa planilha (input) e caso a palavra fosse encontra retornar "Arquivo Encontrado e exibir todas as linhas.
Por exemplo, minha planilha:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nome    Idade   altura
Danilo  27  1.62
João    35  1.75
Maria   23  1.85
Thalita 25  1.80

O usuário buscando Danilo, gostaria que o programa retornasse:
Arquivo Encontrado e 
Nome    Idade   altura
Danilo  27  1.62

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook 
workbook = open_workbook("c:/Python34/test.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
prompt = '>'
print ("Entre com o termo a ser buscado: ")
item = input(prompt)
found = False
for cell in sheet.col(0): 
     if cell.value == item:
       found = True
if found == True:
    print('Arquivo Encontrado', item) # tentei colocar (cell) mas dá errado
else:
    print('Arquivo não Encontrado')
```

Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Particularmente eu gosto mais de trabalhar com csv do que com xls. Basta converter seu xls para csv.

Você pode utilizar regex ou o próprio findall para isso:

```
import re

data = open('seu_arquivo.csv')

texto = "Bem vindo ao python!"

resultado = re.findall(texto, data.read())
```

Isso vai te retornar uma lista com as coisas que encontrou sem precisar ficar fazendo loop de repetição.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou tentar a sugestão, abç